# Confluent Replicator 5.1.2: Class io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter could not be found

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

While deploying confluent-replicator with 5.1.2 version its throwing below error :

> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter for configuration key.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter could not be found.

Using confluent version 5.1.2 and replicator image as: `docker pull confluentinc/cp-enterprise-replicator:5.1.2`

Same works fine if i use docker pull confluentinc/cp-enterprise-replicator:3.3.1

I tried 3.3.1 version it works but it doesn't work with 5.1.2 and 5.2.1

docker pull confluentinc/cp-enterprise-replicator

Ideally plugin for Bytarrayconverter should get added with 5.1.2 version but its not getting added